# How to get random pushed key from firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

i am about to delete the child -MAkugTU_85UTvn4g9Hn by date(timestamp) and videoId value in folowing image

[image]

i tried below code only return the parent called oUi3NI9SdcbCC6v5EmygDNV4lrg1 not the random pushed key, any suggestion will be appreciated. thanks

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const ref = firebase.database().ref('posts').child(uid);
ref.orderByChild('date').equalTo(date).once("value",snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key) // oUi3NI9SdcbCC6v5EmygDNV4lrg1
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('posts').child(uid);
ref.orderByChild('date').equalTo(date).once("value",snapshot => {
   console.log(snapshot.key) // key of parent
   snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      console.log(childSnapshot.key)  //here you will get key of each child
   }
});
```

Then by using child key you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, So can i remove this  child -MAkugTU_85UTvn4g9Hn by using firebase.database().ref('posts').child(uid).child(childSnapshot.key).removeValue();

Comment: @UmeshEswaran Not sure about removeValue() but according to firebase docs you can use remove on a reference to the location of data - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data